# Why was my answer on the "caps in soccer context" question removed?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

From the comments beneath [the answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/118081), there is significant disagreement that it is in fact NAA:

[image]

The [NAA review](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/118081) was completed by a moderator. Another moderator chose to delete. Please explain why it was imperative that this answer be deleted.

Comment: @ColleenV technically, those are the same queue. [They have been for years now.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228861/270345). I find it unlikely the answer was flagged VLQ. My guess at the moment is that one user flagged it NAA, it went to the VLQ review, where one mod acted on it by editing. After that, it might have been flagged again, but in any case another mod acted on it differently.

Comment: "My guess at the moment is that one user flagged it NAA"  To be more precise, three different users flagged it as Not An Answer, and a fourth chose Recommend Deletion in the review queue.  A fifth suggested that it was not an answer in the comments, without reviewing or flagging.

Comment: @snailplane and others seem to agree it doesn't deserve to be deleted. To be precise, 5 people upvoted it. Two argued for the answer in the comments. One person chose to edit it in the review queue. So, why did *you* delete it?

Comment: @snailplane since you seem unable to provide any justification as to why that answer must be deleted, please undelete it.

Comment: Since it doesn't answer the question, I'm not sure that's a good idea.  I could convert it to a comment instead, if you like.

Comment: @snailplane *why* do you think it doesn't answer the question?

Comment: @snailplane - I agree with muru that it should be undeleted. If it doesn't answer the question, let other members downvote it - that's what the downvote feature exists for. Moderators don't just go around deleting answers that are wrong and/or doesn't directly answer the question. There are oodles and oodles of answers that don't answer the question but haven't been deleted, rather, downvoted by other members.

Comment: Congrats, it was undeleted minutes ago!

Answer (score 8):

Adding greater emphasis on the correct meaning in the citation would have probably been enough.

There are dozens, hundreds, maybe even thousands, of posts across the entire network that expand and complement otherwise high-quality answers. These "not really an answer" posts are allowed to stand because they help users get a better overall picture and understanding of the correct answer(s).

The OP could clarify and improve their answer in an edit, for example adding a caveat explaining that the term "cap" is both a verb and a noun and then include a link to a **dictionary definition**, this would help the OP of the question and visitors alike to see why the football/soccer meaning does not apply to the quote.

Comment: I think this is the correct approach. While OP's answer doesn't directly answer the question, it provides important context about another common use of the term in soccer that could easily lead to confusion if not known. I do appreciate that it didn't directly answer the usage in question, but going to deletion before recommending an edit was too quick.